# sed Pattern to Insert Comma between double Quotes

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am very new to sed Regex pattern and stuck with a requirement. I have few Records which i am pulling from Database

> "Name" "Age" "From ABC" "12"

now I am exporting it to CSV with Comma Separated i am using `'s/[[:space:]]\+/,/g'` This Regex

Which is giving me the Result as

> "Name","Age","From,ABC","12"

Which is fine except the Third Column where it has inserted **,** for space
now i want to insert **,** in between double quotes.

Can any One Guide me for the same?

With `'s/"[[:space:]]\+"/","/g'` Regex i Am able to get `"Name","Age","From,ABC","12"` But its is failing when i have `"Name","","From,ABC","12"` it gives `"Name",",","From,ABC","12"`

Is there any other way to counter this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
echo \"Name\"     \"Age\" \"From ABC\" \"12\" | sed -e 's/"[[:space:]]\+"/","/g'
```

which returns

```
"Name","Age","From ABC","12"
```

**edit**

if you want have empty strings `" "` also matched, then you could do this:

```
$ echo \"Name\" \" \"    \"Age\" \"From ABC\" \"12\" | sed -e 's/\("[[:alnum:][:space:]]*"\)/\1,/g' \
    -e 's/",[[:space:]]\+/",/g' \
    -e 's/,[[:space:]]\?$//g'
```

which returns

```
"Name"," ","Age","From ABC","12"
```

The first rules matches strings in quotes (that also may be empty), the second
rule removes the spaces between `,` and the next `"`, the third rules removes
the last `,`.

Comment: Ca you use the backticks in your comment? It's hard to read what is empty space and what is not.

Comment: Thanks it worked Actually but it fails when my column is returning ``" "`` Like ``"Name" " " "From ABC " "12"`` here on second column also it does the parsing which is not required. I wanted it to be like ``"Name"," ","From ABC","12"`` But Indeed it Returned ``"Name",",","From ABC ","12"`` Sorry About not using backticks.

Comment: @AnupamAlok I've made an update of my answer which addresses matching empty strings in quotes `" "`.

Answer (score 6):

Replace `" "` with `","`:

```
sed 's/"[[:space:]]\+"/","/g'
```

*Edited to catch more than one space*

Comment: This is replacing all " "  this is what i got Name Age From ABC 12

Comment: Are you removing the outer single-quote marks? You could instead try: `sed 's/\"[[:space:]]\+\"/\",\"/g'`

Comment: @AnupamAlok: How did you apply the command? `echo '"Name","Age","From,ABC","12"' | sed 's/" "/","/g'` yields "Name","Age","From,ABC","12" for me.

Comment: @AnupamAlok: This `sed` command will give `"Name"," ","From ABC ","12"` Is that not correct?

Comment: ``sed 's/"[[:space:]]\+"/","/g'`` was the Correct and answered my Question but Problem occurred when my data was like ``"Name" " " "From ABC " "12"``  Second column is blank. It gave result as ``"Name",",","From ABC ","12"`` I wanted it in  ``"Name"," ","From ABC","12"``

Comment: @anubhava This Sed Command will Give like ``"Name",",","From ABC ","12"`` not ``"Name"," ","From ABC ","12"``

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s+$//;s/("[^"]*(\\.[^"]*)*")\s+/\1,/g' file
```

Remove any white space at the end of line. Then globally replace any pair of double quoted strings followed by a space(s), by the string followed by a comma.

N.B. This caters for quoted characters (including double quotes) within the quoted strings.